# Layout order which differs from markup order with Susy

Tags: susy-sass, susy

Is it possible to use Susy to create a layout with an order which differs from the order in the markup?

My markup is similar to:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="sidebar1"></div>
  <div id="sidebar2"></div>
</div>
```

This markup makes the mosts sense for mobile where it's presented in a linear fashion (content, sidebar, sidebar).

Desktop however, I would like to present things sidebar, content, sidebar.

My $susy map is:

```
$susy: (
  container: 1200px,
  columns: 12,
  global-box-sizing: border-box
);
```

I've tried

```
#content{
  @include span(7 at 4 of 12);
}
#sidebar1{
  @include span(3 first);
}
#sidebar2{
  @include span(2 last);
}
```

and

```
#content{
  @include span(7 at 4 of 12);
}
#sidebar1{
  @include span(3 at 1 of 12);
}
#sidebar2{
  @include span(2 at 10 of 12);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use float isolation (with the `isolate` keyword), passing in a location (`first`, `last`, `at 10`, etc) only affects gutters and last-flow. With isolation, you can get what you want. Try this:

```
#content{
  @include span(7 at 4 of 12 isolate);
}
#sidebar1{
  @include span(3 first isolate);
}
#sidebar2{
  @include span(2 last isolate);
}
```

You can [read more about isolation in the docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#isolate).

Comment: I wanted to add that using the `first` and `last` keywords achieved the right layout, but introduced stacking order issues that meant links within the content were unclickable. `@include span(2 at 1 of 12 isolate)` and `@include span(2 at 11 of 12 isolate)` worked perfectly.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. As far as Susy is concerned, `first` and `last` are just shorthand for `at X`.